# Azure VPN Gateway P2S Connected but Azure Resource not connected

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

I have been trying the VPN Gateway for few days now, but Point to Site VPN is connected but i cannot able to access the resources through that.

VM and VPNGateway were in same vnet. But could able to establish the connection through private IP address.

Comment: I can able to connect to p2s connection. after Connection successful i cannot able to connect any resources link Vm through Private Ip.

Comment: Do you follow what steps to set up your vpn gateway? Can you RDP or SSH into azure VM with a private IP address from your local client?

Comment: I have followed the every thing, i can able to connect the vpn and it is successful i'm receiving the ip address configured in P2S Address Space. But couldn't able to SSH or RDP through private ip but i can through Public IP. Tried VPN GW Reset as well and tried multiple times.

Comment: Is there any error message when you can't RDP or SSH to the Azure VM? If you deploy another new VM in the same subnet as your existing VM, try to RDP to the new VM, Does this issue exist the same? Also, you can try [IP flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-ip-flow-verify-overview) to verify if the port is blocked from remote ip address(local machine VPN private ip )

Comment: Just I cannot able to Ping or Connect to RDP, Getting Remote Desktop cannot able to connect message. Created NewVm and tried that is also not works, IP Flow showing as allowed from Local Machine VPN Private IP

Comment: Does the Ip flow show that port RDP port 3389 is allowed from your local machine? Can you telnet the private ip of vm with port 3389 or public ip of vm with port 3389 from your vpn client?

Comment: From the VPN client, Open the command prompt as an administrator, can you see the Azure VNet in the Route Table when you input `route print`? If not, I suggest re-downloading the VPN client package and re-connecting the VPN connection.

Comment: Yes route print shows the Vnet Address Space and VPN GW Address Space. I cannot able to telnet the VM RDP Port through Private IP, but i can from Public IP.

Comment: VPNGW Basic SKU is Working but the other sku's aren't